# How do I limit access to API endpoints in Rails 4?

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4, cors

I'm trying to figure out how to limit Cross-Domain access to a JSON API for 3 sites.  It seems you have a few different things to deal with in Rails 4, such as:
`protect_from_forgery with: :exception` which prevents CSRF attacks.

Changing this to `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` seems to allow the world to access it.

Trying this in application.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => 'GET, POST, PUT'
})
```

This, again, allows the world to access your endpoints, however, it only allows a max of one site if you replace '*' with a URL. I'd like at least 3.

There are also gems you could use such as [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors):

In application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins 'http://myFirstSite.com', 'http://mySecondSite.com', 'http://myThirdSite.com'

    resource '/article_pages',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:post],
      :max_age => 0

    resource '/article_pages',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:put],
      :max_age => 0

    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get],
      :max_age => 0
  end
end
```

This latest example is supposed to only allow the sites specified in origins, but seems to allow any site (as I've tested).  I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue but it seems to be configured correctly via their docs.

There are also examples as such: https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4

This one appears to allow ANY site to access the one endpoint inside the controller for which `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` is set in a filter. Again, I'd like to limit the access to 3 sites.

What is a standard way of allowing only a few sites to access one public endpoint while blocking all other sites?

Comment: You might want to look through the rack-cors issues list if you haven't already. This one looked like it might yield some insight: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/24